# Finalizar Request cuando se cambia de pestaña en Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Tengo el problema de que cuando se realiza una request(de carga o de envió de información, o sea siempre pasa) y en ese momento cambio de pestaña o ventana, la carga queda pausada, retomando la "conectividad" cuando vuelvo a la pestaña en la que se efectuo esa request.

Yo necesitaría, que por mas que cambie de pestaña/ventana, la request se complete.

Se puede realizar de forma global en el archivo de configuracion de axios?

He visto el hook beforeDestroy(), que se ejecuta cada vez que cambio de ruta, pero no se si va por ahi la solucion.

Comment: y si la haces en el store directamente?

Comment: que decis de hacer en el store de vuex exactamente?

Comment: Lo que queres hacer que termine.. si estas esperando una respuesta, la guardas en el store.. eso lo podes hacer asincronico, asi aunque haya un cambio, el store deberia terminar.. no?